# Service 'Service' does not implement a ServiceContract type

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Shockingly I can't seem to find any other google results for this error message.

I have created a WCF Service and set it to run on IIS. When I visit the page I see this error message.

My interface has

```
[WebService(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
```

My SVC has:

`public class Service1: IService1`

My understanding that I have the interface containing the servicecontract in place implemented but the error message is telling me not.

Comment: Are you really sure you didn't change the interface name in code and forgot to change it in Web.config?

Comment: Service 'Service' does not implement a ServiceContract type but I can see your service class name is "Service1". so follow @Oscar's advice.

Comment: I changed the Class and Interface name here to obfuscate the project. They are actually mapped to the right names in Web.config and in the class and interface, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you tested that your obfuscated code is giving the same error? If not, is it possible you could post the original code? That would really make it easier for people to help figure out where the issue is.